# for-loop together with await fetch

Tags: javascript, for-loop, fetch-api, console.log

I am executing the code below, and the problem is, the URLS are all running at once. I want the urls to be loaded one by one, after the first URL has been fully loaded. what I suppose to do? I was trying to change the fetch to await fetch, but I recevie the error: "await is only valid in async functions and async generators"

Thank a lot.

```
  for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    fetch("http://www.example.com/post.php", {
      "credentials": "include",
      "headers": {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
      },
      "referrer": "http://www.example.com/index.php",
      "body": "id=",
      "method": "POST",
      "mode": "cors"
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `async/await`.

Create an `async` function so you can `await` inside of it.

```
let fetchExmaple = async function () {
 for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    await fetch("http://www.example.com/post.php", {
      "credentials": "include",
      "headers": {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
      },
      "referrer": "http://www.example.com/index.php",
      "body": "id=",
      "method": "POST",
      "mode": "cors"
    })
  }
}
```

Please have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3vden46k/1/) in order to see how it works with `async/await` and example of a `Promise` (used `Timeout` for demonstration purposes - in your case, it is a `fetch` function which returns a `Promise`).